# Twilio Rest Api CallListRequest return null sometime

Tags: c#, twilio

I am using Twilio rest API for Twilio integration. Below is the sample code.

```
    string AccountSid ="1er23are1t23tete1";
    string AuthToken = "re5s3g5ds2v8f2v";
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
    string trackingNumber ="";
    var request = new CallListRequest();
    request.From = FromPhone;
    request.StartTime = DateTime.Today;
    var calls = twilio.ListCalls(request);
```

Some time ListCalls method is returning null value and I am loosing full integration for this particular inbound call, please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest checking the RestException property on your calls object to see if its null or not.  This will tell you if your request to the Twilio API is failing:

```
if (calls.RestException!=null)
{
    Debug.Writeline(calls.RestException.Message);
}
```

Hope that helps.